# How to get all points to show on ListLogPlot?

Tags: plotting

I have a set of data that I'm trying to plot but some of the points are missing. I've tried correcting this using PlotRange All and //N. Neither of these are showing all the points. My code/data is as below;

```
In[491]:= MyPlot0nm = Thread@{DataVals, Densities}

Out[491]= {{{0.0000100688}, 2.10013}, {{7.64394*10^-6}, 
  0.97578}, {{0.0000124046}, 2.55174}, {{0.0000239139}, 
  4.2032}, {{0.000011998}, 1.8816}, {0.0000227577, 
  5.04169}, {0.0000575172, 6.20468}, {0.0000176255, 3.74308}}
```

If I use list log plot, as below, only the last 3 points are plotted. Any help on this would be massively appreciated!

```
ListLogPlot[MyPlot0nm]
```

Comment: Somehow, you ended up with too many braces in your data structure. Your data should be a set of `{ {x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ..., {xn, yn} }`. In your case, without knowing the structure of DataVals and Densities, you could try this: `reshaped = Partition[Flatten[MyPlot0nm], 2]; ListLogPlot[reshaped, PlotRange -> All]`.